# Modeling trend or seasonality mathematically

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, artificial-intelligence, statsmodels

Using the statsmodels library, the hyperparameters (as output by the ardl_select_order()) for a multivariate time series is (3, 1, 3, 2). the output stands for

Order for Auto Regression =3

Order for Distributed lag = (1,3,2), one value for each exogenous/independent variable

Though I got it how AR & distributed-lag component will get modeled, but I am unable to understand how the trend & seasonality component gets modeled in ARDL by statsmodel? Like assume we have X as dependent variable; W,Y & Z as independent variables for ease

Code for the same

```
  from statsmodels.datasets.danish_data import load
  from statsmodels.tsa.api import ARDL
  from statsmodels.tsa.ardl import ardl_select_order
  data = load().data
  data = data[["lrm", "lry", "ibo", "ide"]]

  sel_res = ardl_select_order(data.lrm, 3, data[["lry", "ibo", "ide"]], 3, ic="aic",trend="c")
  print(f"The optimal order is: {sel_res.model.ardl_order}")

  res = sel_res.model.fit()
  res.summary()
```

References: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/autoregressive_distributed_lag.html, https://otexts.com/fpp2/useful-predictors.html

Comment: What specifically are you having difficulty with? `ardl_select_order` has optional parameters for both seasonality and trend (see [docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ardl.ardl_select_order.html)).  So, for example, if your data has monthly frequency and say all January's look alike, you have seasonality with a 12-month period, so you would set `seasonal=True` and `period=12`.

Comment: Got it, but how the equation looks like? The mathematical form of representing trend & seasonality @AlexK

Comment: The full equation is given in the first link you posted.  There can be non-linear (e.g., quadratic) time trend terms added, as shown in the equation, but those are not implemented here.  You can include a constant term and/or a linear trend (the first two terms in the equation).  For seasonality, the equation shows `s-1` dummy variables for seasons, with each one having its own coefficient to be estimated.